# How to make an end to end app connection with ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile-application

Is there any possibel way to connecting two or more ionic apps to each other? for example realtime or true time negotiation, sendind text, medais or information (directly and end to end)sharing?

Comment: Are the apps on the same device, or two different devices? On the same device they can communicate, but if not, you would probably be better off making use of a server, and having both devices communicate to the same server. I don't think it's possible to have two devices communicate directly, unless Ionic incorporates NFC or similar.

Comment: @ObsidianAge, On two different devices which can be hundreds of KMs far. so pushing data to server is easy how to push data from server to other end/ends.google push notification is not my preferred solution i had to push data in app.  something like messengers/whatsApp, ...

Comment: I think you are in to https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/WebSockets